Why are the rendered images so dark?
I am new to blender and I want to render an image using different cameras to have different views of an image. I started out with trying to render the most basic cube using different cameras. 100 cameras are being used here and I used Python API for that. The code I used is
import bpy
import os

scene = bpy.context.scene
cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]

view_layer = bpy.context.view_layer

light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name="New Light", type='POINT')
# Create new object with our light datablock.
light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="New Light", object_data=light_data)

# Link light object to the active collection of current view layer,
# so that it'll appear in the current scene.
view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection.objects.link(light_object)

# Place light to a specified location.
light_object.location = (4, 51, 55)

# And finally select it and make it active.
light_object.select_set(True)
view_layer.objects.active = light_object



num_cameras = 100
focal_length = 70

cube.location = (0, 50, 50)


def add_constraint(camera: bpy.types.Object, obj_to_track: bpy.types.Object):
    constraint = camera.constraints.new(type='TRACK_TO')
    constraint.target = obj_to_track
    constraint.track_axis = 'TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z'
    constraint.up_axis = 'UP_Y'

def set_camera_prop(camera: bpy.types.Object, focus_obj: bpy.types.Object, focal_length 
= focal_length, name = "camera_"):
     camera.name = name
     camera.data.lens = focal_length
     camera.data.dof.focus_object = focus_obj


for i in range(0, 10):
    for j in range(0, 10):
        bpy.ops.object.camera_add(location = (10, i*10, j*10))
        current_camera = bpy.context.object
        set_camera_prop(current_camera, cube, focal_length= focal_length, name = 
        f"cam_({i},{j})")
        add_constraint(current_camera, cube)


for obj in scene.objects:
    if obj.type == "CAMERA":
        scene.camera = obj
        # scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
        print('Set camera %s' % obj.name )
        file = os.path.join("outputs1/", obj.name )
        scene.render.filepath = file
        bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )'''

However, the rendered images are very dark, and nothing like what is being directly being rendered in Blender. Where am I going wrong? Some of the rendered images are as below




Have you added lights? Do shift+A > light > sun. Rotate it a little bit and you should have everything lit.

By default light objects have a power of 10W when you create them, which has a very small falloff if you want to light more distant objects. You need to adjust it to your scene. Try something like light_data.energy = 1000 after creating the point light.

@BenedictsForester The first bit of the python code (which I'm not familiar with) seems to show that he's added a Point light, but I can't see if he's set its power.

@Gorgious adjusting the light energy worked, thank you!

@Gorgious please post an answer ;) The comments section should really be only for comments.

By default light objects have a power of 10W when you create them, which has a very small falloff if you want to see more distant objects. You need to adjust it to your scene.
Add this line after creating the point light :
light_data.energy = 1000
You can increase the value even more if you don't see its light bouncing off of your object.
